# Windows device driver: FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME on raw partition - Access is Denied

Tags: windows, driver, device

I am currently writing a Windows utility that does a similar job as Linux dd. But this utility only copy USED block instead of cloning the whole disk block by block.

**The way I write it is to** 
*
(1) Copy MBR from disk A which contains three partitions to disk B.
(2) after step A. I am able see three *raw* partitions from disk management GUI. (no drive letter, no file system).
(3) Copy each partitions from A to B in a loop.*

**The problem I have is:**
in step (3) after I get the file handle from OpenDevice and I try to use that handle to lock a raw partition, I get Access Denied (error 5) and I am 100% sure that my program did not accidentally hold the lock somewhere else.  My dev and testing environment is Windows 2003 server and my utility is executed as Admin privilege.

Here is the code snippet:

```
   ...
   shareMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
   fHandle= OpenDevice(shareMode); 
   res = DeviceIoControl(fHandle, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dummy, NULL); 
    if (res == 0)
    {
         DismountAndLockVolume();
    }
    ...
```

in my OpenDevice function in use:

```
DWORD access = (fOpenMode==forWriting) ? (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | SYNCHRONIZE) : GENERIC_READ| SYNCHRONIZE;

 NTOpen(&fHandle, fName.c_str(), access, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, shareMode,   FILE_OPEN,FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_RANDOM_ACCESS|FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE);
```

to get the file handle(fHandle).

In DismountAndLockVolume function, I try to dismount this volume and grab the lock on it again.

```
DeviceIoControl(fHandle, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dummy, NULL);

DWORD shareMode = FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ;

ntStatus = OpenDevice(shareMode);

res = DeviceIoControl(fHandle, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dummy, NULL);
```

The problem is, when I my code try to dismount this volume, an exception is thrown due to access denied.

Then I browsed the Internet and get the following discussion thread: QUOTE

> A write on a volume handle will succeed if the volume is not mounted by a
>   file system, or if one of the following conditions is true:
>   1. The sectors to be written to are boot sectors.
>   2. The sectors to be written to reside outside of file system space.
>   3. You have explicitly locked or dismounted the volume by using
>   FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME or FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME.
>   4 . The volume has no file system. (In other words, it has been mounted
>   as a RAW volume.)
>
> A write on a disk handle will succeed if one of the following conditions
>   is true:
>   1. The sectors to be written to do not fall within a volume's extents.
>   2. The sectors to be written to fall within a mounted volume, but you
>   have explicitly locked or dismounted the volume by using FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME
>   or FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME.
>   3. The sectors to be written to fall within a volume that is not mounted
>   or has no file system.
>
> The modification of some disk parts, like the boot sector ( upto 16 ), is
>   still allowed . But my utility relies on raw write access to the disk. I am
>   not able to lock volume by FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME. Result is ACCESS DENIED. While
>   searching through net i come to know that kernel mode driver is only
>   solution. But in this group i come to know driver is not require. I work on
>   services and pass through SCSI, but i am not able to find the solution. If
>   kernel mode driver is require then what kind of driver it should be ?
>
> Is anybody know the solution of the problem then please help me out

This thread terminates with no conclusion. Can somebody give me a hand on what was going on? Any hint for possible solution?

Millions of Thanks. I have been scratching my hair for days :-(((.

Comment: `I am 100% sure that my program did not accidentally`, it's the other ones you have to worry about.  Including malware scanners and whatnot.

Comment: READ MBR from source
WRITE MBR to Target
Refresh Drive
(1)get new partitions info on target 
(2) get disk geometry 
(3) FAILS: error code 21 (device not ready)
Copy partition one by one
(1)copy the first partition 
(2) open disk stream for write 
(3)Lock first new partition 
(4)FAILS: error code 5 (access is denied.) 

I guess there should one more step involved to active the new partitions before I can lock it.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to dismount a raw partition.  Does opening the volume device succeed?  What error code is returned from the first attempt to lock the volume?  Have you tried rebooting the system after copying the MBR and then locking the volume device?

Comment: When I've worked with volumes I've always used either GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE as appropriate, I'm not sure whether SYNCHRONIZE is supported.  Try either GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_ALL and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, have you considered copying the entire drive as a single unit rather than copying each partition separately?  Alternatively it might be worth creating the target partitions using IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX and associated functions rather than by copying the MBR.  Copying the MBR might not work properly if the geometry of the target disk isn't identical to that of the source disk.

Comment: Thanks Harry for helping me out.

Regarding to your previous three comments: (1) It doesn`t make sense to dismount a raw partition. Opening newly created partition succeeds. If I only copy MBR from one disk to the other,after seeing newly created partitions on target disk, get disk geometry fails with error code 21(device not ready) and subsequently FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME fails with error code 5 (access is denied). I have manually created partitions on target drive using Windows disk manager and later DO NOT copy MBR and I end up with the same error.

Comment: (2) not including SYNCHRONIZE  doesn`t help either :-( (3) See my reply to comment (1), even if I manually create partitions on target drive using disk manager, I will encounter exactly same sequence of errors. However, If I manually create partitions, assign drive letter and do a quick format, then the whole program works like charm. So now, it leaves me nowhere to go except for programmablely create partitions and perform quick format.

Comment: The problem is that Microsoft does not provide a convenient API to do such kind of work. The closest API that I can find is *SHFormatDrive*, but "The format is controlled by the dialog interface. That is, the user must click the OK button to actually begin the format—the format cannot be started programmatically".

Comment: reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/b1a9db91-3ab4-4fed-bd47-4597b5fcb9eb
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762169(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you tried opening the raw partition by specifying 0 as the sharing mode?  If that succeeds, then you don't need to use FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME as you already have exclusive access.